# git push rejected for a reason that I don't understand

Tags: git

I work with git. I am on my local branch feature/truc-9_0_0 which was created from branch version/9.x.x. I want to update my local branch.

So I run

```sh
$git checkout version/9.x.x
$git pull
$git checkout feature/truc-9_0_0
$git rebase version/9.x.x
```

and afterwards, when I run

```sh
$git push --set-upstream origin feature/truc-9_0_0
```

I have the following error message

```sh
To https://bitbucket.machin.lan/scm/am/truc.git
 ! [rejected]          feature/truc-9_0_0 -> feature/truc-9_0_0 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.machin.lan/scm/am/truc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

then I tried to run `$git pull` but I have the following error message

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/moca-9_0_0
```

Should I run

```
$git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/truc-9_0_0 feature/truc-9_0_0
```

If you can explain me what happened, it would be nice.

Comment: Why does the error message say feature/moca-9_0_0 if you are on feature/truc-9_0_0? Are you telling the truth?

Comment: When you did the rebase of your feature branch, did you have that state of the feature branch already pushed to the remote repository? Or are those commits, which you want to rebase, only locally? Because the error message seems to indicate that you rebased commits, which were already pushed to the server. In that case you either have to force push your commits (which has other drawbacks), or you have to use a merge locally, when you want to update your feature branch.

Comment: what is the return of the command  ̀git remote -vv` ?
I suspect that your local branch does not track a remote branch

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I deleted my remote branch and I recreated it by a push and everything has been put in orderThe discussion is closed. Thank you